# Use QEMU Guest Agent with Windows guests and Virt-Manager

Tags: debian, windows, qemu

I can't get the mentioned combination get to work.

I installed the `vioserial` driver in the guest, installed the Guest Agent and added the Qemu Guest Agent channel to the VM.
Both guest services are running.
I checked the permissions in `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/*`.

Still, the "Fit resolution" option under "View" is greyed out with the tooltip "No connection to guest agent".

Host is Debian stable, guests are Windows 7 Pro and Windows 10 Pro (x64).
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need spice agent for copy & paste and automatic resolution switching. just install `spice-guest-tools-latest.exe` from here: https://spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/

Download Page: https://spice-space.org/download.html

Quote:

> This installer contains some optional drivers and services that can be installed in Windows guest to improve SPICE performance and integration. This includes the qxl video driver and the SPICE guest agent (for copy and paste, automatic resolution switching, ...)